# examine the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n+(-1)^{n+1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have no idea how to examine the convergence of the series:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n+(-1)^{n+1}}$$

We can see that $\frac{(-1)^n}{n+(-1)^{n+1}} \to 0$.
However we can't use criterium Leibniz and Dirichlet because of the fact that $\frac{1}{n+(-1)^{n+1}}$ is not monotonic.

The only thing that it is easy to check is that this series is not absolutely convergent:
$$\left| \frac{(-1)^n}{n+(-1)^{n+1}}\right|=\frac{1}{n+(-1)^{n+1}}\ge \frac{1}{n+1}$$

Comment: Consider joining adjacent terms. That is, $n=2k,2k+1$,$$\frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{2k+2}$$

Comment: for big enough $n$, the $(-1)^n$ in the denominator plays no role----

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I don't know what do you mean ? Could be more precisely ?

Comment: Thomas Andrews's expressions allows too (exchanging $a_{2k+1}$ and $a_{2k+2}$) to get the limit $\log(2)-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a_n\to 0$ then $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_n$ converges if and only the series:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (a_{2k}+a_{2k+1})$$ converges.

In your case, $a_{n}=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n+(-1)^{n+1}}$, and $$a_{2k}+a_{2k+1}=\frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{2k+2}=\frac{3}{(2k-1)(2k+2)}$$

Use comparison test to show that $\sum \frac{3}{(2k-1)(2k+2)}$ converges, and hence your original series converges.

Comment: Ok, It is also ok to do: $a_{2k}+a_{2k+1} = \frac{1}{n-1} + \frac{-1}{n+1} = \frac{2}{n^2-1}$.  It is obviously convergent.  However, I don't understand this theorem.  Look, $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ is convergent.  However, $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{2k}}{2k} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$ - none of them is not convergent.  Where am I wrong ?

Comment: No, if $n=2k$ then $a_{n}+a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{n-1}+\frac{-1}{n+2}$. You forgot that $a_{n+1}=\frac{-1}{(n+1)+1}$. There are plenty of cases of alternating series where the sum exists but neither half converges. That is why you don't split them in half. If $\sum a_{2k}$ converges and $\sum a_{2k+1}$ converges then $\sum a_k$ converges, but not visa versa. @HaskellFun

Comment: Ok, so we have theorem: If $a_{2k}+a_{2k+1}\wedge a_n \to 0$ is covergent then $\sum a_n$ is covergent. Yeah ?  I know also other theorem (similar): If $\sum a_{2k} $ and $\sum a_{2k+1} $ are covergent then $\sum a_n$ is also covergent.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. One may recall the Taylor series expansion, as $x \to 0$,
$$
\frac1{1-x}=1+x+O(x^2)
$$ giving, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\frac{(-1)^n}{n+(-1)^{n+1}}=\frac{(-1)^n}n\frac{1}{1-\frac{(-1)^{n}}n}=\frac{(-1)^n}n+\frac1{n^2}+O\left( \frac1{n^3}\right)
$$ then, there exists some $n_0\ge1$ such that for all $N\ge n_0$, one has
$$
\sum_{n= n_0}^N\frac{(-1)^n}{n+(-1)^{n+1}}=\sum_{n= n_0}^N\frac{(-1)^n}n+\sum_{n= n_0}^N\frac1{n^2}+\sum_{n= n_0}^NO\left( \frac1{n^3}\right)
$$ leading to the *convergence* of the initial series by letting $N \to \infty$.

Comment: @Haskell Fun Are you Ok with my answer above? If not please feel free to tell me how I can improve it.

Comment: Your solution is great, however I would like to see way with hint of Thomas Andrews.  Could you add second way of solution ?